# Differentiating URI and request body parameters in same servlet request

Tags: java, rest, servlets

I would like to imbue my API with the ability to set values on a range of objects in a single call.  A seemingly logical solution is for the user to define in the ranges in the URI and set the desired new values in the request body.  For example the URI would be:

```
/api/horses/?color=brown
```

In the request body, the key/value pair would be

```
key: color
value: red
```

This will turn all of our brown horses red.

The problem is that getting parameters from the HttpServletRequest object does not let you determine if the parameters were set in the URI or the body.

Perhaps there are two questions here:

1. If there is different, generally accepted RESTful way to set values on a range of objects in a single call, what is it?
2. If using both URI and request body parameters is ok, how do you differentiate between those in the HttpServletRequest object?

**Update**: The accepted answer addresses how to differentiate (the second of the enumerated questions).  To address the general challenge for updating a range of values, I decided that this can be best accomplished by limiting to only one updated field and specifying the field in the path.  Like so:

```
PUT /api/horses/color?from=brown&to=red
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that you have a name clash between parameters encoded in the request line and parameters encoded in the POST body.

You can always differentiate by calling:

- `HttpServletRequest.getQueryString()`
- `HttpServletRequest.getInputStream()`

obviously you then have to use a URL library for parsing the query string (the encoded/decoder in the JDK is ok) and library for the form data, depending on the encoding (I recall some Apache project called commons-codec for this).

I'd go the simplest route of not having name clashes - for example by prefixing URL parameters with *filter-* but there's no standard rule for this.